# Filtered dropdowns

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

This has been bothering me for a while, I am creating a web app which has the potential of having a ton of records. People will be able to navigate from record to record using the select dropdowns. My question is as follows, how do you create a dropdown which shows the size of your database records.

For example. You have an app which lists the amount of potholes in a specific state and city. A state like California. I have two drop-downs, one for the state, another for the city.

So, on my first dropdown I select the state "California (300 potholes)". My 2nd dropdown dynamically lists the cities within the state and shows the values (i.e. City A (50), City B (100), City C(150)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDGft.png)
This is what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I'm looking for a dynamic select menu that shows the size/count of records in my database for each matching option within the dropdown.

How is this done?
Is it possible to do this on Rails?

Comment: You seem to be asking a few things here, but the UI element of what you're describing is known as cascading dropdowns, using that as your search term should help with that part.

Comment: This is a bit old, but able to provide some details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. I would to add the value of the dropdown menus next to the name. |California 300| --> 2nd dropdown | City A (100)| City B (50)| City C (150)| Getting the dropdown to display the values in it is very hard

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You use ul li to create a dropdown and then have a db query which shows the values next to the name..

Thanks for all the help